# Big Query SA360 Data Transfer Error - Permission denied: the SA360 user does not have read access to the report scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, google-cloud-data-transfer, google-sa360-api

I have a problem setting up a data transfer from SA360 (the old api) to Big Query.

In SA 360 I've two subaccounts. I set up the data transfer for one sub-account without problems, and the data syncs to BigQuery.

The other sub-account causes an error:

PERMISSION_DENIED: Error from API in SendRequestReportRequest for table 'AccountStats'. Error code: conditionNotMet. Message: Permission denied: the SA360 user does not have read access to the report scope.

I'm an admin of both of sub-accounts and use the correct agency and advertising IDs.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this before? Any clues on how to solve the problem are appreciated.

I tried to spot the difference between the set-ups but there is nothing that would differentiate them apart from the agency id and advertising id.